# Why n-region is more thicker than p-region in PIN diode when reversed biased?

Tags: semiconductor-physics

when we reversed biased the PIN diode why intrinsic region is more towards the P side than n side [image]

Answer (score 2):

When this is a drawing of the doping profile then the diode was just designed asymmetrically like that. If the border lines of the  $p_+$ and $n_+$ regions with the intrisinsic region  illustrate the  boundaries of the depletion zone under reverse bias, and the doping profile is actually symmetric, then this could be a conseqence of a lower doping in the p than in the n region.